# C# Mobile Device Windows Mobile 6 Enter Key not working

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, keyevent

Hi All
I have a problem with my mobile device. I have a textbox on my form and i write a code for key_down event

```
if(e.KeyKode==Keys.Enter)
{
    //
    //
}
```

but My mobile device not press the enter key.How can i make?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same functionality as you, and the code you post works fine for me, just Debug it and look which key code is launching, I supose you're associating the event to the KeyDown event of your control.

```
textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.YourEvent);
```

Hope this works for you.

See you.

PS: If you had some more code to show to us, we could look for the solution mor precissely